# Filter dates which are earlier than today?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

In my application I have a list of NSDate instances. At one point I need to seperate the dates which are past to today ie `[NSDate date]` (earlier to morning 12)
And I have used the logic like below. I feel there must be a better logic than this, so help me if there is better solution.

I pass the date instance as an argument to this method which will return a BOOL value corresponding to my requirement.

```
-(BOOL)checkIfPast:(NSDate *)date
{
    NSDate *today=[NSDate date];
    NSUInteger dateFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit;
    NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components1=[gregorianCalendar components:dateFlags fromDate:today];
    NSDateComponents *components2=[gregorianCalendar components:dateFlags fromDate:date];
    if (components2.day-components1.day<0) {
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to at least also compare month, year (and era). Do that in opposite order.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe oh I forget thak you

Comment: Simplest is to get an NSDate value for 12AM today and then compare NSDate values.  (Note that the NSDate value must be adjusted for the timezone you wish to compare for.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
BOOL checkIfTodayOrFuture(NSDate *date)
{
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSUInteger dateFlags = NSCalendarUnitEra | NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay;
    NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [gregorianCalendar components:dateFlags fromDate:now];
    NSDate *midnight = [gregorianCalendar dateFromComponents:components];
    return [date compare:midnight] == NSOrderedDescending;
}
```

If you have to make a lot of tests keep `midnight` around and just do the `compare:` on all of the dates.

Keep in mind that the result is not constant. For example, the user might change her timezone so the interval of "today" also changes.

Answer (score 1):

See `NSDate`'s `earlierDate:` method

Answer (score 1):

Create the Date for 12Am and make a Compare. The result says asc or dsc. I think asc is the One You want